# JS how to execute contructor in class more times (odd times)

Tags: javascript

In my case constructor is executed one time per creating new instance of class (new Product()). If I create instances of this class even times my method initAccordion wont work as i want to - I want to toggle class .active of .product element.

I want to execute contructor allways odd times.

Mine task is to build class which will toggle class active in .product element.

```js
class Product {
  static count = 0;
  constructor() {
    this.instanceId = ++Product.count;
    this.initAccordion();
  }
  initAccordion() {
    const thisProduct = this;

    // console.log(thisProduct);
    const clickableTriggers = document.querySelectorAll('.product__header');
    for (let clickableTrigger of clickableTriggers) {
      clickableTrigger.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const products = document.querySelector('.product');
        console.log(Product.count);
        products.classList.toggle('active');
      });
    }
  }
}

new Product();
new Product();
new Product();
new Product();
```

```css
.product.active .product__description {
  display: block;
}

.product .product__description {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <article class="product active">
      <header class="product__header">
        <h3 class="product__name no-spacing">
          ZIO STEFANO'S DOUGHNUT
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down product__icon"></i>
        </h3>
        <p class="product__base-price no-spacing">$9</p>
      </header>
      <div class="product__description">Lorem</div>
    </article>
    <article class="product active">
      <header class="product__header">
        <h3 class="product__name no-spacing">
          ZIO STEFANO'S DOUGHNUT
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down product__icon"></i>
        </h3>
        <p class="product__base-price no-spacing">$9</p>
      </header>
      <div class="product__description">Lorem</div>
    </article>
    <article class="product active">
      <header class="product__header">
        <h3 class="product__name no-spacing">
          ZIO STEFANO'S DOUGHNUT
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down product__icon"></i>
        </h3>
        <p class="product__base-price no-spacing">$9</p>
      </header>
      <div class="product__description">Lorem</div>
    </article>
    <article class="product active">
      <header class="product__header">
        <h3 class="product__name no-spacing">
          ZIO STEFANO'S DOUGHNUT
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down product__icon"></i>
        </h3>
        <p class="product__base-price no-spacing">$9</p>
      </header>
      <div class="product__description">Lorem</div>
    </article>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you want your code to behave? Are you trying to make it so that each call to `new Product()` adds a click event listener to the next available article/product? If so, I would suggest using `id`s instead for this so that when you instantiate an instance of `Product` you can specify which class element you want a listener attached to rather than relying on instantiation order.

Comment: Your goal isn't clear